# Is there an emacs game for practicing cursor control?

Tags: emacs, controls, text-cursor

So I was wondering if there's a game out there that lets me practice my emacs cursor skills. I just started using emacs and thought that a game letting me control the player with the standard emacs bindings would be an awesome way to get going. When searching for one I stumbled upon [this](http://vim-adventures.com/) for VIM.

Does anyone know of something similar for emacs?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a game, but I'd suggest installing [`hardcore-mode`](https://github.com/magnars/hardcore-mode.el) (available on Melpa too), and configure it to your liking (*here's [my configuration](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-hardcore.el) if interested*). That package when enabled globally will force you to **not** use the arrow keys and use the `C-f`, `C-b`, `C-n`, `C-p` bindings instead. So much so that now using those bindings has become a second nature to me.

---

*PS: There's an [emacs-dedicated stackexchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) in case you didn't know.*

Answer (score 1):

One idea: Have a game mode that shows two buffers, and the goal is to transform the first into the second buffer with the least amount of keystrokes.

Comment: That game does exist: it's called [vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com) and there is a good Emacs mode for it you can find on MELPA.

Comment: Amazing stuff guys. The world of emacs never ceases to amaze me